# DOMDocument add attribute to root tag

Tags: php, html, dom, domdocument

I want to make function that adds some attributes to root tag of given html.

I'm doing this:

```
    $dom = new \DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($content);

    $root = $dom->documentElement;

    $root->setAttribute("data-custom","true");
```

And for `$content='<h1 class="no-margin">Lorem</h1>'`

It returns:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html data-custom="true"><body><h1 class="no-margin">Do more tomorrow. For less.</h1></body></html>
```

While should be just:

```
<h1 data-custom="true" class="no-margin">Lorem</h1>
```

How to make DOMDocument not create doctype, html, body tags, but just operate on given html and how to select the root node(s) of given html

Ps. I will never use regex to manage html.

Comment: Well, you have talked about the root element and also used `documentElement` – which is `HTML` in the case of HTML documents. You should think about what you are trying to achieve and rephrase your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you output the HTML, select a specific node rather than the whole document:

```
<?php

$content = '<h1 class="no-margin">Lorem</h1>';

$dom = new \DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($content);

$node = $dom->getElementsByTagName('h1')->item(0);
$node->setAttribute('data-custom','true');

print $dom->saveHTML($node);
// <h1 class="no-margin" data-custom="true">Lorem</h1>
```

Alternatively, as it's well-formed, treat the content as XML to avoid extra HTML tags being added:

```
<?php

$content = '<h1 class="no-margin">Lorem</h1>';

$dom = new \DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($content);

$dom->documentElement->setAttribute('data-custom','true');

print $dom->saveXML($dom->documentElement);
// <h1 class="no-margin" data-custom="true">Lorem</h1>
```